# Function name must be a string lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

when i try to execute this command :"php artisan make:controller UserController"
i got this error message in CMD : 
"In web.php line 22:
Function name must be a string"

This the web.php file:

```
    $router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});



$api= $router('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('vl,',function ($api)
    {
         $api->group(['prefix'=>'oauth'],function($api){

             $api->post('token','\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');

         });


         $api->group(['namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers','middleware'=>['auth:api','cors']],function ($api){

             //controller route
         });


    });
```

Comment: And what line is 22?

Comment: what line is 22?

Comment: line 22 is :  $api= $router('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

Comment: You can't just call `$router('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router')`, in all likelihood `$router` in this context is an instance of `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router`, which is not invokable as a function.

What exactly are you trying to achieve with that line?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see it:

```
$api->version('vl,',function ($api)
```

there was a comma on 'vl,'.

```
$api->version('vl',function ($api)
```

Comment: I try it but the same issue, i following this tutorial  :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWoJ2YbdrWU